# How are French Grande size(47" x 63") movie posters printed?

Tags: print-design, print-production, posters, art, paper-size

I'm really curious, what kind of printing press were used to print the French movie posters to 47" x 63"?

Comment: idk that particular spec, but just google "large sheet offset" The shop I used to work at could do 1.4x1m sheet-fed, no problems. 63" is 1.6m so it wouldn't need a much larger press than the ones I used to operate.

Comment: I have no idea what printer they used but they sell roll printers that are 126" wide. I have a printer that is 98" wide, so it's possible to print that size.

Comment: Which French movie posters? When were they printed?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, grande movie posters are printed either with inkjet (digital) or with offset printing, depending on the required run length.

Large format inkjet only matured in this century. Before that, it was either offset printing or screen printing (also known as silk screen).

Screen printing method was especially good at laying down a thick layer of ink, and so it was popular with billboards and posters that had to keep their bright color for weeks in a row, despite sun and/or rain.

(The "grande" movie posters in my 90's dorm room were silk screen printed. I remember that you could feel the thickness of the ink, which, I learned later, is impossible with offset)